# widevine plugin not installing on firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, drm, widevine

I'm using Firefox version 89 on mac and I'm not able to play DRM content because the `widevine` plugin is not installing.

Below is the message displayed in addon

`Widevine Content Decryption Module provided by Google Inc. will be installed shortly`

steps I have tried to resolve the issue -

1. Refresh firefox removing all the addons and extensions
2. Reinstalling and deleting profile under firefox folder
3. toggling off vpn as mentioned [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1294397)

please help me to sort the issue and let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: Did you share your browser console network when you try to install with the VPN off - if you did and can share here that may help others suggest solutions to you?